# Vaadin heatmap does not support 40x40 (1600) points?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14, vaadin-charts

In Vaadin 14.6.1, I tried to create a Vaadin heatmap foollowing the documentation / example from [here](http://%20https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/ds/components/charts/charts-charttypes/#charts.charttypes.heatmap).

However, I encountered a few problems/questions, listed in descending order of importance below:

1. The heatmap supported 30 rows by 30 columns; but when I tried 40 rows by 40 columns, the entire heatmap showed a single color (blue in my case).
2. Is it possible to manually set the minimum numeric value and maximum numeric value for the color scheme. This way, if I plot my data one day and it has values in the range of 0 to 1, but on another dataset from another day, the numeric values range from  between 0 and 0.5, the color scheme *range* won't automatically change (to being between 0 and 0.5) and confuse the user.
3. In the [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/ds/components/charts/charts-charttypes/#charts.charttypes.heatmap), it has the following methods listed, but they do not seem to exist in Vaadin 14.6.1

```
plotOptions.setBorderColor(SolidColor.WHITE);
plotOptions.setBorderWidth(2);
```

4. When I hover over the datapoints, is there a way that the tooltip can *only* show the numeric value (and not the x, y coordinate or the series name etc.?)
5. Is there any limit to the number of datapoints? I'm hoping that if #1 above is resolved that I can plot a 100 by 100 (ie 10,000) point heatmap.
6. If I plot 100by100, there will be many labels on the x and y axis. In my case, the x and y axis are actually numerical, so I did what the documentation suggested and just placed category labels in the xaxis and yaxis spots. However, is there any way to only display every "nth" label, so that the x-axis and y-axis is not so crowded? (This would essentially mimic what Vaadin does for normal line charts' xaxis and yaxis).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not that experienced with Vaadin Chart, but these are the questions that I can comment on:

(1) With 40x40 items you go over the threshold of 1000 in which the Chart switches into "turbo" mode for performance reasons. This seems to not be compatible with the heatmap series. You can disable turbo mode by setting `plotOptions.setTurboThreshold(0);`

(2) Unfortunately the `ColorAxis` doesn't support this, it only has an API for min and max color. Definitely a valid use-case though, and it seems to be supported by the Highcharts library that the Vaadin Chart uses under the hood. You should consider opening a feature request for this in the [Github repo](https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components).

(3) This seems to be a documentation issue. The methods are available in later Vaadin platform versions, but not in 14.6.

(5) In theory not, but in practice there will be a huge performance hit in the browser due to the excessive amount of DOM elements (quick test of 100x100 froze the browser for 10s). I'm afraid the component isn't really made for such extreme use-cases. In this case it might be better to utilize a low-level JS drawing library using the canvas, or draw an image on the server-side and display that in the browser. Maybe you can also consider modifying your use-case so that you only display one slice of your data and allow the user to switch between slices.